# Add a className if the className has specific CSS property values

Tags: jquery, if-statement

So far I've tried this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
if ($('.heading-title').css('color') === 'rgb(168, 168, 168)') {
    $('.heading-title').addClass('heading-title-x');
} });
```

This code adds the class name to each class with "heading-title". But I need to add the class name which only has this specific CSS property value.

Comment: You'll need to loop through `$(".heading-title").each...`, check each one then use `$(this).addClass` - you can't use `this` with your code as-is, only inside an `each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to see each element on document ready.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  $('.heading-title').each(function() {
    if($(this).css('color') === 'rgb(168, 168, 168)') {
      $(this).addClass('heading-title-x');
    }
  });
});
```

(edited)